# ToggleClass with bxSlider

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I have an issue  with Jquery UI. Actually I want to  create a simple slider. I am using bxSlider with Jquery. But i want actually to change the background  of my page each time i change the picture in the slider. I am using this code actually:

```
var updateAfterSlideTransition = function() {
        if (slider.settings.infiniteLoop) {
            var position = '';
            // first slide
            if (slider.active.index == 0) {
            console.log(slider.active.index);
            $('body').toggleClass('body0', 1000).removeClass();
                // set the new position
                position = slider.children.eq(0).position();

            } else if (slider.active.index == 1) {
            console.log(slider.active.index);

                $('body').toggleClass('body1', 1000);

            } else if (slider.active.index == 2) {
            console.log(slider.active.index);

                $('body').toggleClass('body2', 1000);

            } else if (slider.active.index == getPagerQty() - 1 && slider.carousel) {
                position = slider.children.eq((getPagerQty() - 1) * getMoveBy()).position();
                // last slide
            } else if (slider.active.index == slider.children.length - 1) {
                position = slider.children.eq(slider.children.length - 1).position();
            }

            if (slider.settings.mode == 'horizontal') {
                setPositionProperty(-position.left, 'reset', 0);
                ;
            } else if (slider.settings.mode == 'vertical') {
                setPositionProperty(-position.top, 'reset', 0);
                ;
            }
        }
        // declare that the transition is complete
        slider.working = false;
        // onSlideAfter callback
        slider.settings.onSlideAfter(slider.children.eq(slider.active.index), slider.oldIndex, slider.active.index);

    }
```

And it actually works when i use my slider normally (from left to right) but when i try to use it backwards it doesnt work. If you have any idea to make it simple or better, feel free to answer :)

Comment: consol.log(slider.active.index) and see what happens when you go backwards, then just change it in your script

Comment: did it already Johnny . The slider index is the right one each time :).

Comment: When do you call this method? Can you post your whole code so I can have a better idea of what's like..

Comment: Edit. I actually modify the code of bxslider.js by adding those lines .

Comment: try to remove the integer in toggleClass(), so only $('body').toggleClass('body1') i.e.

Comment: Nope. It doesnt change anything. Actually the integer is just the time for the background to fade in so i dont think it is the main problem here.

Comment: There is no fade option according to the jQuery api for toggleClass

Comment: i am actually using jquery ui: http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i am just checking the bxSlider plug-in and i think you can apply a function like this:

```
function classes () {
    $('body').removeClass();
    var activo = $('.bx-pager-item .active').attr('data-slide-index');
    var clas = 'body'+activo;
    $('body').addClass(clas, 300);
}
```

View this Demo and ask any question **http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3RM/344/**

Comment: oh hi Danko and thanks, thats exactly what i was looking for . Thats a great work. Only one problem: the transition doesnt work if you hit the spots below the slider . How can i do this ?

Comment: apply the function to those items `$('.bx-pager-item a')`